# ModuleNotFoundError when mocking while using pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest

I'm using pytest for writing unit tests in my django project.
But when I want to mock a method in following code:

```
@patch('smspanel.services.sms_panel_info_service.get_buinessman_sms_panel')
def test_send_plain_sms_success(mocker, businessman_with_customer_tuple):

    mocker.return_value = SMSPanelInfo()
    customer_ids = list(map(lambda e: e.id, businessman_with_customer_tuple[1]))
    businessman = businessman_with_customer_tuple[0]
    message = 'message'
    result = services.send_plain_sms(user=businessman, customer_ids=customer_ids, message=message)
    smsq = SMSMessage.objects.filter(
        businessman=businessman,
        message_type=SMSMessage.TYPE_PLAIN,
        status=SMSMessage.STATUS_PENDING,
        message=message)
    assert smsq.exists()
    sms = smsq.first()

    receivers_count = SMSMessageReceivers.objects.filter(sms_message=sms, customer__id__in=customer_ids).count()
    assert receivers_count == len(customer_ids)
```

I get following error:

```
thing = <module 'smspanel.services' from 'C:\\Users\\Pouya\\Desktop\\programs\\python\\marketpine-backend\\smspanel\\services.py'>
comp = 'sms_panel_info_service'
import_path = 'smspanel.services.sms_panel_info_service'

    def _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path):
        try:
            return getattr(thing, comp)
        except AttributeError:
>           __import__(import_path)
E           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smspanel.services.sms_panel_info_service'; 'smspanel.services' is not a package

c:\users\pouya\anaconda3\lib\unittest\mock.py:1085: ModuleNotFoundError
```

**My test file is locate in smspanel/tests/test_services.py.**

Comment: Show services.py.

Comment: I found the problem. I had an nested import statement inside my send_plain_sms method and had to change the mock path